# How do get value between () in java string just before .?

Tags: java, regex

I have to replace file name `abc(1).jpg` to `abc(2).jpg` . Here is the code

```
 String example = "my attachements with some name (56).jpg";
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d{1,}).\\)").matcher(example);
 int a = 0;
 while(m.find()) {
    a=Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
String p = example.replace(String.valueOf(a), String.valueOf(a+1));
 }
```

It is working fien as per given use case . But fails in case of  `abc(ab)(1)(ab).jpg`   for this case it just changed to `abc(ab)(2)(ab).jpg` . Which is not required . So how do i can verify that numeric bracket is just before dot i.e .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
String example = "my attachements with some name (56).jpg";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\)\\.)").matcher(example);
example = m.replaceAll(r -> String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(m.group())+1) );
System.out.println( example );
// => my attachements with some name (57).jpg
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Syeq4m). The regex used is

```
(?<=\()\d+(?=\)\.)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YMctq4/1). It matches

- `(?<=\()` - a  location immediately preceded with `(`
- `\d+` - then consumes 1+ digits
- `(?=\)\.)` - immediately followed with `).` char sequence.

If you need to tell the regex to match the dot that is the last dot in the string (where it is most likely the extension delimiter) replace `(?=\)\.)` with `(?=\)\.[^.]*$)`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YMctq4/2).

Comment: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
?<=\()\d+(?=\)\.)
^: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
?<=\()\d+(?=\)\.)

Comment: @VivekSahni See the [demo I linked to](https://ideone.com/Syeq4m) in my answer, there are no errors. What is your Java version?

Comment: @VivekSahni I think you copy/pasted the pattern without the `(` and ruined the lookbehind.

Comment: @VivekSahni Did you pay attention at the last two lines in my answer? I suspect it is exactly that scenario. In Java: `"(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\)\\.[^.]*$)"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead regex for this:

```
"\\((\\d+)\\)(?=\\.)"
```

`(?=\.)` is a lookahead condition that asserts presence of dot right after closing `)`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nGAKoh/1)